# Probability after rolling 4 dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

Q. (the probability that the total after rolling 4 fair dice is 21) > (the probability that
the total after rolling 4 fair dice is 22)

A. Explanation: All ordered outcomes are equally likely here. So for example with two
dice, obtaining a total of 9 is more likely than obtaining a total of 10 since there are
two ways to get a 5 and a 4, and only one way to get two 5’s. To get a 21, the outcome
must be a permutation of (6, 6, 6, 3) (4 possibilities), (6, 5, 5, 5) (4 possibilities), or
(6, 6, 5, 4) (4!/2 = 12 possibilities). To get a 22, the outcome must be a permutation
of (6, 6, 6, 4) (4 possibilities), or (6, 6, 5, 5) (4!/22 = 6 possibilities). So getting a 21
is more likely; in fact, it is exactly twice as likely as getting a 22.

What I have understood so far is that after rolling 4 fair dice you can get 22 in the following ways -

- 6,6,6,4 - $4C_1$ - 4
- 6,6,5,5 - $4C_2$ - 6

So the total ways in which you can get 22 is 10, where you can get 21 in the following ways -

- 6,6,6,3 - $4C_1$ - 4
- 6,6,5,4 - $4C_2$ - 6
- 6,5,5,5 - $4C_1$ - 4
  and hence the total ways in which you can choose is 14.

Am I doing something wrong here?
Can someone please help me understand the answer (A.) a bit better?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $12$, not $6$ ways to get a permutation of $6,6,5,4$. You can choose the position of the $5$ in $4$ ways, then choose the position of the $4$ in $3$ ways.

This gives us $4+12+4 = 20$ ways to get a total of $21$, and $4+6=10$ ways to get a total of $22$, and so we conclude that rolling a $21$ is twice as likely.

Comment: So can I assume that 6,6,5,4 can be chosen in $4C_1 * 3C_1$ ways? (After choosing 5 in 4 ways, choose 4 in 3 ways?)

Comment: Yes, that's one way to think about it. If you're familiar with [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients), there are $\binom{4}{2,1,1} = \frac{4!}{2!1!1!} = 12$ ways to get a permutation $6,6,5,4$.